# Ignore unchecked checkbox in GET form

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, get

I am using a piece of code to ignore empty input boxes when processing a form with the GET method. It is working for the text inputs but not for the checkboxes I have in the form. The code I am using is

```
function SubmitForm(pForm) {
var getString = "";
var elems = pForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if(elems[i].type == "submit") {
        continue;
    }
    if(elems[i].value != "") {
        getString += encodeURIComponent(elems[i].name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(elems[i].value) + "&";
    }
    }
    window.location = pForm.action + getString;
return false;
    }
```

The HTML for my form is

```
<form action="game_finder.php?" method="GET" onsubmit="return SubmitForm(this);">
<input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="Warhammer 40k">Warhammer 40k&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="Kill Team">Kill Team&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="Warhammer Quest: Blackstone Fortress">Warhammer Quest: 
 Blackstone Fortress&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="Necromunda">Necromunda&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: All your checkboxes _have_ a value, so `elems[i].value != ""` will of course never be true for them. You want to check whether they are `checked` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the checkboxes are checked because you are already assigning values to the checkboxes.

Refer below code snippet.

```js
function SubmitForm(pForm) {
  var getString = "";
  var elems = pForm.elements;
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].type == "submit") {
      continue;
    }
    if (elems[i].type == "checkbox" && elems[i].checked == true) {
      getString += encodeURIComponent(elems[i].name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(elems[i].value) + "&";
    }
    if ((elems[i].type == "text" || elems[i].type == "select-one") && elems[i].value != "") {
      getString += encodeURIComponent(elems[i].name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(elems[i].value) + "&";
    }
  }
  window.location = pForm.action + getString;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> -->
</head>

<body>
    <form action="game_finder.php?" method="GET" onsubmit="return SubmitForm(this);">
        <input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="Warhammer 40k">Warhammer 40k&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="Kill Team">Kill Team&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="Warhammer Quest: Blackstone Fortress">Warhammer Quest:
 Blackstone Fortress&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="Necromunda">Necromunda&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
   </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this did it thanks. just need to get it to work for my select dropdown now.

Comment: @Foster Updated above snippet to accommodate the select dropdown.